# UpdateById method in Spring Reactive Mongo Router Handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

In Spring Reactive Java how can I write an `updateById()` method using the Router and Handler?

For example, the Router has this code:

```java
RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.PUT("/employees/{id}").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .and(RequestPredicates.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
        employeeHandler::updateEmployeeById);
```

My question is how to write the `employeeHandler::updateEmployeeById()` keeping the ID as same but changing the other members of the Employee object?

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> updateEmployeeById(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<Employee> employeeMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(Employee.class);

    <And now what??>

    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(employeeMono, Employee.class);
}
```

The Employee class looks like this:

```java
@Document
@Data  
@AllArgsConstructor  
@NoArgsConstructor  
public class Employee {

    @Id
    int id;
    double salary;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to add `ReactiveMongoRepository` in your classpath. You can also read about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive).

```
    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Employee, Integer> {
        Mono<Employee> findById(Integer id);
    }
```

Then your `updateEmployeeById` method can have the following structure:

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> updateEmployeeById(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
            .bodyToMono(Employee.class)
            .doOnSubscribe(e -> log.info("update employee request received"))
            .flatMap(employee -> {
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(serverRequest.pathVariable("id"));
                return employeeRepository
                        .findById(id)
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException("employee with " + id + " has not been found")))

                        // what you need to do is to update already found entity with
                        // new values. Usually map() function is used for that purpose
                        // because map is about 'transformation' what is setting new
                        // values in our case
                        .map(foundEmployee -> {
                            foundEmployee.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                            return foundEmployee;
                        });
            })
            .flatMap(employeeRepository::save)
            .doOnError(error -> log.error("error while updating employee", error))
            .doOnSuccess(e -> log.info("employee [{}] has been updated", e.getId()))
            .flatMap(employee -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(BodyInserters.fromValue(employee), Employee.class));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on Prana's answer, I have updated the code above merging our solutions in one. Logging with a help of Slf4j was added. And `switchIfEmpty()` functions for the case when the entity was not found.

I would also suggest your reading about [global exception handling](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors#global) which will make your API even better. A part of it I can provide here:

```
/**
 * Returns routing function.
 *
 * @param errorAttributes errorAttributes
 * @return routing function
 */
@Override
protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
}

private HttpStatus getStatus(Throwable error) {
    HttpStatus status;
    if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        status = NOT_FOUND;
    } else if (error instanceof ValidationException) {
        status = BAD_REQUEST;
    } else {
        status = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    return status;
}

/**
 * Custom global error handler.
 *
 * @param request request
 * @return response
 */
private Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(ServerRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, false);

    Throwable error = getError(request);
    HttpStatus errorStatus = getStatus(error);

    return ServerResponse
            .status(errorStatus)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's perfect. Could you please explain why map is used to assign the values from the new employee ? Regards.

Comment: Two things that I observed: (1) there should be no " ;" after the .flatMap(employeeRepository::save); and (2) when try to update, it updates the value but throws an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE].

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful to you. I've also updated my answer and added a part related to exception handling. Please, have a look. Probably, it helps you as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version of the above worked without any exceptions:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> updateEmployeeById(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

        Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound().build();

        Mono<Employee> employeeMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(Employee.class);
        Integer employeeId = Integer.parseInt(serverRequest.pathVariable("id"));

        employeeMono = employeeMono.flatMap(employee -> employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .map(foundEmployee -> {                 
                    foundEmployee.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                    return foundEmployee;
                })
                .flatMap(employeeRepository::save));

        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(employeeMono, Employee.class).switchIfEmpty(notFound);
    }
```

Thanks to Stepan Tsybulski.